# Sphinx поиск по всему сайту rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

Пытаюсь реализовать глобальный поиск по статьям и по рецептам на сайте с помощью Sphinx

Вот мои индексы для рецептов:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :recipe, with: :active_record do

    # fields
    indexes title, sortable: true
    indexes summary
    indexes description

    # attributes
    has user_id, created_at, updated_at
end
```

Вот для статей:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :post, with: :active_record do
    # fields
    indexes title, sortable: true
    indexes content

end
```

На данный момент у меня такие связи в моделях :

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many    :ingredients
    has_many :recipe_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :recipe_categories

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :post_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
```

В принципе поиск можно реализовать так

```
@search = ThinkingSphinx.search(params[:search])
```

Но проблема заключается в том что бы выводить записи с картинками по поиску от статей и рецептов одновременно, возникает ошибка что не находит метод **recipe_image** либо **post_image** (картинки добавлены с помощью гема paperclip)

Выдачу всех рецептов реализовал так

```
<div class="entries row">
    <% @search.each do |recipe| %>
        <div class="entry one-fourth wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="<%= cycle(".2s", ".4s", ".8s") %>">
            <figure>
                <%= image_tag recipe.recipe_image.url(:medium) %>
                <figcaption>
                    <%= link_to recipe_path(recipe) do %>
                        <i class="ico i-view"></i> <span>Просмотреть рецепт</span>
                    <% end %>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="container">
                <h2><%= link_to recipe_path(recipe) do %><%= recipe.title %><% end %></h2>
                <div class="actions">
                    <div>
                        <div class="difficulty"><i class="ico i-medium"></i><%= link_to recipe_path(recipe) do %><%= recipe.difficulty %><% end %></div>
                        <div class="likes">
                        <%= link_to like_recipe_path(recipe), method: :get do %>
                            <i class="ico i-likes"></i>
                            <%= recipe.get_likes.size %>
                        <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <%= link_to recipe_path(recipe) do %>
                                <i class="ico i-comments"></i>
                                <%= recipe.comments.count %>
                            <% end %>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Подскажите как правильно сделать, что бы еще выводились статьи в результатах поиска.

Создавать отдельно поиск для статей и рецептов не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Пугающе просто:

```
render @search
```

...и просто сделайте те шаблоны, которые он у вас попросит в возникающих сообщениях об ошибках. Таких должно возникнуть по одному на модель.

Не нужно никаких `@search.each do |item|` и подобного. Rails может рендерить массивы (и другие коллекции) объектов самостоятельно, выбирая для каждого объекта соответствующий шаблон, вызвав у него `.to_partial_path`.

---

#### Что нужно знать о partial'ах:

Когда Rails рендерит коллекцию объектов, он выбирает для каждого объекта шаблон, исходя из `to_partial_path`, а название переменной из `model_name`. Обычно получается, что для модели `Item` рендерится `items/_item.html.<шаблон>` и в нём рисуемый объект лежит в переменной `item`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35785/discussion-on-answer-by-d-side-sphinx-----rails).